# C# SqlDataReader only returning 16 rows?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this code here:

```
var cmd = _ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[uspM501_Get]";
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter Param1= new SqlParameter();
Param1.ParameterName = "@Param1";
Param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
Param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
Param1.Value = aircraft;

SqlParameter StartDate = new SqlParameter();
StartDate.ParameterName = "@StartDate";
StartDate.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime;
StartDate.Value = start_date;

SqlParameter EndDate = new SqlParameter();
EndDate.ParameterName = "@EndDate";
EndDate.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime;
EndDate.Value = end_date;

cmd.Parameters.Add(Param1);
cmd.Parameters.Add(StartDate);
cmd.Parameters.Add(EndDate);
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
    //execute code 
}
```

which is targeting this stored procedure

```
SELECT *
  FROM table t
  WHERE t.VarChar = @param1
  AND t.datetime >= CASE
                                   WHEN @StartDate IS NULL
                                   THEN convert(datetime,'19010303',112)
                                   ELSE @StartDate
                               END
  AND t.datetime <= CASE
                                   WHEN @EndDate IS NULL
                                   THEN CONVERT(datetime,'20170303',112)
                                   ELSE @EndDate
                               END
```

(varchar and datetime are not the columns names, but that is the datatype of the columns I am checking against, in case that makes any difference.)

When I run the stored procedure as regular sql, it returns the 135 rows I expect for my test case parameter, none of which have any null values. However, when I step through the code and check the return, `reader.Read()` returns false after 16 iterations, for this and all 3 other test cases I ran. I'm not sure if this means anything, but `reader.HasRows` returns true, which from other examples I've looked at should mean that `reader.Read()` should return values? Are there settings or something that I could look at, I haven't found anything after looking through google, but I am very new to C# so I could just not be asking the right questions.

Comment: `reader.HasRows` indicates that the reader *has rows*, not that the reader has *more* rows.  Make absolutely certain you're hitting the same database in your code.

Comment: You can run SQL profiler to see the exact stored procedure call so that way you can make sure the parameters are the same as when you run it manually.  Obviously there is a difference, you're just not seeing it.

Comment: I just checked and it is for sure the same database that I am running the query on.

Comment: @JoelHines - Do what `Rick S` suggested, attach *Sql Profiler* and see what is actually being sent to the database. That is a sure way to figure out what the difference is.

Comment: The sql profiler showed me what I expected to see, it is calling everything it should and sending the information I expect. Should it show anything besides the stored procedure and the parameters you are sending?

Comment: Can you add the code you're using to run the stored procedure manually?

Comment: You should definitely run a trace as mentioned above, but I feel the issue stems from the DateTime conversion.

Comment: So I found out that even if the param doesn't exist, it only returns 17. I ran the raw query with one I knew didn't exist, and then I compared that with the procedure, and the procedure returned 17.

Comment: When you use `DateTime` it is the ACTUAL date time (i.e.,) date + time. Have you checked whether this parameter  date + time, is as you expect it to be ?